# Can the concentration of values in a raster map be known?

Tags: raster, grass-gis

I have a generated raster map containing different flood levels. Is there a grass script to determine the percentage of values in a raster map? I'm thinking of using r.mapcalc to solve this, but I'm not yet sure how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

I think the function you need is [r.stats](http://www.phygeo.uni-hannover.de/grass/grass62/manuals/html62_user/r.stats.html)

If your data is floating point, you will need to play around with the bucketing/quantization parameters such as *nsteps*